# C - Nary Tree: error while appending a new child to the tree

Tags: c, tree, children, appendchild

I'm developing a Nary Tree in C using a structure like this:

```
typedef struct sNaryNode { 
     int *data; // Point to the node ’s data
     int n; // The number of children 
     struct sNaryNode **child; // The child list
} NaryNode; 

typedef NaryNode NaryTree;
```

I can't use a List (as required into the project).
I'm able to create the Tree, but when I try to append a new child to the Tree, all the "data" value of the Tree are overwrited with the new value. For example: I create the root with `data = 1`, then I want to append a new child with `data = 2`, at the end both the root and the new child have the same "data" value, that is `data = 2`. I think that the problem is not due to a mistake with pointers management, but since I don't know where I'm wrong, I decided to ask your opinion. Here is the full code: 
 **lm_array2.h**

```
#ifndef lm_array2_h
#define lm_array2_h

typedef struct sNaryNode { 
     int *data; // Point to the node ’s data
     int n; // The number of children 
     struct sNaryNode **child; // The child list
} NaryNode; 

typedef NaryNode NaryTree;
typedef void (*DataFreeFunc) (const void *);

void printArrayTree (NaryTree*);
NaryTree *createNode (int, int*);
void freeTree (NaryTree*, DataFreeFunc);
int appendChild(NaryNode*, int*);
void deleteChild (NaryTree*, int, DataFreeFunc);

#endif
```

**lm_array2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lm_array2.h"

void printArrayTree (NaryTree *tree) {
    int d = *tree->data;
    printf("\n %d ", d);
    if (tree->n > 0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < tree->n; i++) {
            //printArrayTree (tree->child[i]);
            int dd = *tree->child[i]->data;
            printf("\n %d", dd);
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("\n-----\n");
        return;
    }
}

NaryTree *createNode ( int children , int *data) { 
    // Allocate space for a new NaryNode in memory
    NaryNode *node = (NaryNode*) calloc (1 , sizeof (NaryNode) );

    // Set the contents of the NaryNode appropriately
    node->data = data; 
    node->n = children ; 
    node->child = (NaryNode**) calloc ( children , sizeof (NaryNode*) );

    // Return the node we initialized
    return node;
}

void freeTree (NaryTree *tree , DataFreeFunc dFree) {
    unsigned i; 

    // Don’ t try this with a NULL pointer 
    if ( tree == NULL) return; 

    // Free the children recursively 
    for ( i = 0; i < tree->n; ++i ) 
        freeTree ( tree->child [ i ] , dFree); 

    // Free the child array 
    free ( tree->child ); 

    // Free the data if a function is provided 
    if (dFree) dFree( tree->data); 

    // And finally , free the structure 
    free ( tree ); 
}

 int appendChild(NaryNode *root , int *data) {
     // Increment the degree of the node 
     root->n++; 

     // Reallocate the child array (n children in the child array) 
     root->child = (NaryNode**) realloc ( root->child , ( root->n)*sizeof (NaryNode*) );

     // Add the newNode into the child array and increment degree 
     root->child [ root->n - 1] = createNode (0 , data); 

     // Return the index of the child we just inserted 
     return root->n - 1;  
 } 

 void deleteChild (NaryTree *root , int idx , DataFreeFunc dFree) {
     unsigned i; 

     // Delete the child 
     freeTree ( root->child [ idx ] , dFree); 

     // Remove the defunct child 
     for ( i = idx ; i < root->n - 1; ++i ) 
        root->child [ i ] = root->child [ i - 1]; 

     // And finally , reallocate 
     root->n--; 
     root->child = (NaryNode**) realloc ( root->child , ( root->n)*sizeof (NaryNode*) );
 }
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lm_array2.h"
#include "lm_array2.c"

void menu(int*);

int main() {
    NaryTree *aTree = (NaryNode*)malloc(sizeof(NaryNode));
    int choice = 0, value;

    printf("\nEnter the root value: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    aTree = createNode (0, &value);

    do {
        menu(&choice);
        switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the new child value: ");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                //NaryTree *aNode = createNode (0, value);
                appendChild(aTree, &value);
                break;

            case 2:
                //printf("%d", *aTree->data);
                printArrayTree(aTree);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\n\n***THE END***\n\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice > 0 && choice <= 2);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void menu(int *choice){
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Insert new child\n");
    printf("2. Print NaryTree\n");
    printf("3. Exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &*choice);
}
```

All the code (except the main) is taken from here --> [CLICK HERE](https://kylelemons.net/download/Complex_Data_Structures_N-ary_Tree_PDF.pdf)

Every help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the initialization of your Node: you don't alloc the memory buffer for the data. You make it point to your parameter, that is on the stack and not on the heap. As soon as your `createNode`function end, the stack is emptied and your parameter (so your data value) is lost.

```
NaryTree *createNode ( int children , int *data) { 
    // Allocate space for a new NaryNode in memory
    NaryNode *node = (NaryNode*) calloc (1 , sizeof (NaryNode) );

    // Set the contents of the NaryNode appropriately
    // node->data = data; 
    node->data = malloc(sizeof(node->data));
    *node->data = *data;
    node->n = children ; 
    node->child = (NaryNode**) calloc ( children , sizeof (NaryNode*) );

    // Return the node we initialized
    return node;
}
```

Or, more simpler:

```
typedef struct sNaryNode { 
     // int *data; // Point to the node ’s data
     int data; // contains the node ’s data
     int n; // The number of children 
     struct sNaryNode **child; // The child list
} NaryNode;
```

And pass to `createNode` the int data directly and not a pointer:

```
NaryTree *createNode ( int children , int data) { 
    // Allocate space for a new NaryNode in memory
    NaryNode *node = (NaryNode*) calloc (1 , sizeof (NaryNode) );

    // Set the contents of the NaryNode appropriately
    // node->data = data; 
    node->n = children ; 
    node->child = (NaryNode**) calloc ( children , sizeof (NaryNode*) );

    // Return the node we initialized
    return node;
}
```